# Is it possible to create custom operator syntax for custom Swift types?

Tags: swift, option-type, syntactic-sugar

I like the syntax `Type?` as sugar for `Optional<Type>`. I want to try to leverage this with my own types. For instance, I have a slightly more-extended version of Optional that tells you *why* something has no value, called `DescriptiveOptional<Type>`, and I want to, for instance, denote this with something like `Type~?`. I tried the following:

```swift
postfix operator ~?



public postfix func ~?<T>(lhs: T.Type) -> DescriptiveOptional<T>.Type {
    return DescriptiveOptional<T>.self
}
```

But then the syntax becomes like:

```
let foo = DescriptiveOptional<String>.success("Value")
let bar = String.self~?.success("Value")
```

Still shorter, but I don't like the taste of it. Also, it leaves things like  this impossible:

```
func baz(_ x: String~?) {}
// Errors:
//    Expected parameter name followed by ':'
//    Expected ',' separator

func hoge(_ x: String.self~?) {}
// Errors:
//    'self' is not a member type of 'String'
//    Expected parameter name followed by ':'
//    Expected ',' separator

func qux(_ x: String.Type~?) {}
// Errors:
//    Expected parameter name followed by ':'
//    Expected ',' separator
```

**So is there a way to make my own syntactic sugar for my type?**

Comment: AFAIK custom Type declaration syntax like that isn't supported in Swift. You could do a typealias to shorten the declarations, but ~ and ? are reserved symbols so could not be used.

Comment: Besides that...DescriptiveOptional is an odd design choice in the first place. The point of Optionals is that there's nothing there, not "there's something here but not the thing you thought it might be". Explaining _why_ something's optional is the point of Error handling.

Comment: @PeejWeej `~` is not reserved; you can make a `prefix func ~(foo: Foo) -> Foo` no problem. Since this starts my operator, `~?` is also valid. I've confirmed this with unit tests.

Comment: @PeejWeej I understand; please trust that I have good reason to instate this pattern.

Comment: Reserved for operators. You can't use it in type/function/var names

Comment: I can trust that you _think_ you have a good reason ☺️

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, if you believe the answer is "The best you can do is a `typealias`", then I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @PeejWeej Seems the Swift community likes this pattern which I call `DescriptiveOptional` a lot, but just calls it [`Result`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/Prototypes/Result.swift) ([SE-0235](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0235-add-result.md))